# How to disable cache for development only in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to disable caching when running ASP.NET core application in Development environment. How can i do that?

I'm setting cache up in Startup:

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

I want to disable cache in templates, which use the `<cache>` tag:

```
<cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600)">
```

Comment: Could you show how you setup caching or if you don't can you show/explain what's cached?

Comment: @AntonToshik i've added setup/use case

Comment: I assume you are looking for a 1 line of code on/off switch kinda thing and do not want to specify which parts to turn off explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply inject `IHostingEnvironment` into the startup constructor of your `Startup.cs`

Like So

```
      private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;

       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration,IHostingEnvironment environment)
       {
        _environment = environment;
        Configuration = configuration;
       }
```

Then you can use the private `IHostingEnvironment` inside your configures services method .

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
 if(!_environment.IsDevelopment())
    services.AddMemoryCache();
}
```

EDIT :

After rereading the question the cache tags should be disabled aswell.
I would suggest adding a flag inside your `appsettings.devlopment.json` called`"PageCachingEnabled": "false"` .

On the view I would then inject the configuration like so

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
<cache enabled=@Boolean.Parse(Configuration["PageCachingEnabled"]) expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600)">
```

Comment: @KunalMukherjee He wants to disable caching when the asp net core environment variable is set to "Development" ie the environment variable on the machine. There is an abstraction of code contained within the `IHostingEnvironment` concrete implementations which provide helper functions around the current environment setup. In the above code Memory cache will only be added if the environment is Not Development therefore "disabling" it. Unless I misunderstood the question this is what he wanted to achieve

Comment: so he can just go and set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable from the build settings right

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Well yes ? But he only wants this not to happen on development , I fail to see how simply changing that variable magically fixes this issue , just changing that variable may lead to completely other configuration being loaded in from the appsettings.json transform. His current code will always add memory caching regardless of environment. My answer simply introduces the concept of adding the caching when he is not in Development.

Comment: Internally `_environment.IsDevelopment()` just goes and checks `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` if its set to `Development` or not

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use `services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();` in development, this will use the memory of the running system as a cache.

```
if(Env.IsDevelopment()) {
  services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
} else {
  services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache();
}
```